# How to set input for Azure Function to fetch table row in Azure Store?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm using the Azure portal to create my Azure Functions for my game. Right now I've set op storage with a table that is named gamesTable.

I've then had an Azure Function that is an HTTP trigger called GetGame and the thought is it should provide an id of the game (earlier created) and this id is the partition key in the table.

However, I'm having some problems understanding what to do with the window I've pasted below. As the HTTP request comes to the function, the table should be an input, and the result of the HTTP request should be to return the table column "Data" for that row with that id.

My table entity:

```
public class Game
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

The documentation states that I have to provide partition key **and** row key. The request does not know about the row key. It should work with the query filter then and only take one. But how does that work? Query filter = 'PartitionKey eq header.partkey'? There header.partkey is a header in my request? Does anyone know how to set the context to the Query filter?

[image]

Comment: You need to look up output bindings from functions to table storage

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

You might be able to use the binding that uses CloudTable. That allows much more complex queries. Offical docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#input---c-example---cloudtable

**Option 2**

You can choose to not use the table storage input binding, instead read the table from your code inside the function. In my experience, azure functions input bindings remove boilerplate code for *common* scenarios. For example, with table storage input binding, one doesn't have to write the code to connect to storage account. But the common scenarios don't always cut it. You end up losing some control. If it's making things hard, it's ok to write the code on our own.